# Select top 10 records calculated by amount spent over a period of time?

Tags: mysql

Currently I'm struggling on retrieving top 10 records calculated by amount spend over a period of time.

MySQL table:

```
create table `payment_holder` (
    `user_id` int (11),
    `amount` Decimal (6),
    `date_added` datetime 
);
```

Demo data:

```
insert into `payment_holder` (`user_id`, `amount`, `date_added`) values('4','3.75','2012-03-15 00:41:39');
insert into `payment_holder` (`user_id`, `amount`, `date_added`) values('5','32.20','2012-03-15 00:42:10');
insert into `payment_holder` (`user_id`, `amount`, `date_added`) values('6','32.20','2012-03-15 00:42:58');
insert into `payment_holder` (`user_id`, `amount`, `date_added`) values('7','0.89','2012-03-15 00:48:05');
insert into `payment_holder` (`user_id`, `amount`, `date_added`) values('8','3.75','2012-03-15 00:50:54');
insert into `payment_holder` (`user_id`, `amount`, `date_added`) values('4','3.75','2012-03-15 00:41:39');
insert into `payment_holder` (`user_id`, `amount`, `date_added`) values('5','32.20','2012-03-15 00:42:10');
insert into `payment_holder` (`user_id`, `amount`, `date_added`) values('6','32.20','2012-03-15 00:42:58');
insert into `payment_holder` (`user_id`, `amount`, `date_added`) values('7','0.89','2012-03-15 00:48:05');
insert into `payment_holder` (`user_id`, `amount`, `date_added`) values('8','3.75','2012-03-15 00:50:54');
```

I would like retrieve a result like the following it from this example:

```
user_id amount
------------------
6       64.40   
5       64.40   
4       7.5 
8       7.5 
7       1.78
```

So in short, which `user_id` has the highest amount of purchases based on `date_added` in 2012?

Comment: I do not see 2012 in your data.. do you mean 2011?

Comment: @bonCodigo yeah sorry copied random data from table. I'll fix to 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something like this which will return all data for all years:

```
select user_id, sum(amount) Amount
from payment_holder
group by user_id
order by amount desc
limit 0, 10
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cd348/7)

But if you want to limit by year, you can add a `WHERE` clause which will apply the `YEAR()` function to the `date_added` field:

```
select user_id, sum(amount) Amount
from payment_holder
where year(date_added) = 2012
group by user_id
order by amount desc
limit 0, 10
```

Comment: Just like i need, damn i really have struggle with orders and groups :(

Comment: @arma it takes time and practice, You will get it though. :)